# Discovery of Ed25519 128-bit private key where a KDF has not been used

Tags: elliptic-curves

If there is a uniformly random 128-bit private key scalar $x$, with the corresponding public key $X=xG$ (where $G$ is a well-known base point), how difficult would it be to discover $x$ from $X$?

I am aware that the regular approach would be to use a KDF to derive a private key in the range of the group size of the base point (approx. $2^{252}$). However, this is for use in a commitment scheme where there are specific reasons that the 128-bit private key is used directly.

Please also note that this isn't a question about the difficulty of forging signatures, and is specifically limited to discovering the exact value of $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This computation seems to be tantalisingly within reach of current capabilities. The best known approach is to use a variation of [Pollard's kangaroo method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_kangaroo_algorithm) where $O(\sqrt {|I|})$ elliptic curve group operations are used where $I$ is the interval in which $x$ lies. This would mean roughly $2^{64}$ group operations for your problem. The naive statement of work of 64-bits feels well within the capabilities of modern computers, but here each unit of work involves several multi-precision multiplications of 255-bit numbers which are non-trivial contributions that add perhaps another 10-20 bits of work depending on how the group is implemented and how the multiplication is implemented.

In practice then, the nearest result is by [Zieniewicz and Pons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm_records#Elliptic_curves) who in 2020 recovered a discrete logarithm on the sec256k1 from an interval of size 112-bits. This took them 13 days on 256 NVIDIA GPUs. Your problem is roughly 8-bits harder (group operations are slightly cheaper on Ed25519 than on sec256k1, but will not have a major effect). Fortunately, Pollard's kangaroo is highly parallelisable. If we

- (questionably) assume a 1-bit improvement from Moore's law in the past two years
- buy 4x as many GPUs
- let them run for slightly over 1 year

then your problem should be solvable.